# Get name value of spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I use the following content within a spinner:

```
<string-array name="spinner">
    <item name="true">Test</item>
    <item name="false">Test 2</item>
</string-array>
```

Now withing my method I can get the current content of the spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
value= Boolean.parseBoolean(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Here is the spinner XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_content"/>
```

But the issue is, that this method returns `Test` or `Test 2`. But I need the value that is stored within the `name` of the `item`, so `true` or `false`.

How can I get this value instead?

Comment: Spinner is a view and a string array, correct?

Comment: If so, have you considered fetching the content array, finding the item based on content name, then retrieving the itemName from here? Not a very sleek implementation, but it looks like there's a step missing in your implementation.

Comment: I hoped that there is maybe something like `.getSelectedItemName().toString()` or something similar...

Comment: Can you show me your Spinner xml or java where you set the spinner content? You're using this widget, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html correct?

Comment: Can you post the adapter of your spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Test")){
    value = true;
}else if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Test 2")){
    value = false;
}
```

Comment: This is super tightly coupled. Would advise a more dynamic approach

Comment: also, I think you meant 'string.contentEquals(otherstring)'

Comment: I see. Yes, I believe there is a fundamental flaw in the setup